# Can you specificy a related video for a short through YouTube Data API v3

Tags: automation, youtube, youtube-data-api

YouTube now offers the possibility to [add a related video to your YouTube Shorts](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/14075157?hl=en).

I wondered if there was a way to do it when uploading a video using the [Videos: Insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) endpoint.

(Since this a somewhat new feature, API support for this might not exist yet.)

Comment: I doubt it. YouTube API is not updated and does not have the same functionalities as the website.